# How to create a Grant Login Users View?

Tags: list-view, grant-login-access

I want to create a view in my Users list, so only those that I have Grant Login access to, will be displayed.

I can use the: Login access Date > Today - as the filter, but how do I get the link to: `Login as user` ?

[image]

Comment: The link appears to take the form: `https://{pod}.salesforce.com/servlet/servlet.su?oid={orgId}&suorgadminid={targetUserId}&targetURL=%2Fhome%2Fhome.jsp`. When I created a similar view the Action column still had the Login link. Is that what you are after?

Comment: I want to FILTER only those I have the access to.

Comment: I got the impression from your question you were going to use "the Login access Date > Today" as the filter to find those users and only needed the login link. Is that not the case?